# OpenVPN missing in "connection type dialogue" in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, network-manager, openvpn

I need to connect to my work computer with an openVPN connection, this is something that I have successfully set up on my Ubuntu 12.04 in the past, so I'm alright with with how to do this in theory. I was using the "network dialogue" thing, selected "add connection", then "open vpn" and filled in the location of the config files, so no problem here.

With the new Ubuntu 13.04, this option has now disappeared and it only offers me "saved VPN" or "PPTP", neither of which would work or accept my config files.

I tried to follow the instructions on the net on using the terminal and installed the odd program, but can't get it to work. Is there any way that I could make the aforementioned network manager dialogue to accept my OPEN(!)VPN again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install the package **network-manager-openvpn-gnome**. You can search for it in Software Center or just open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```