# Add OpenVpn in ubuntu 16 04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, openvpn

How to add **OpenVpn** in my `VPN Connections` - `Configures Vpn` - `Network Connections`?

Look at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787399/openvpn-in-ubuntu-16-04), and video in this question, but list hasn t openvpn.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find solution in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/316303/626183). I just need to write in terminal this command to add OpenVpn in my connections:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```